# mvc4 bundling minification not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I got a bundling problem in my release-mode on IIS7
(Asp.net mvc 4)

in my BundleConfig:

```
 var vTickerJs = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/vtickerjs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/vticker/jquery.vticker.*"
            );
        bundles.Add(vTickerJs);
```

In my Partial:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/vtickerjs")
```

on my Harddisk:

```
 E:....\Scripts\vticker\jquery.vticker.js
```

There is a difference between IIS-Express on my local system - Here it works and the above mentioned Partial has:

```
<script src="/Scripts/vtickerjs?v=-d007Ef_5pa18P48liUylZoCJuP69zO53AEJrSmBH841"></script>
```

BUT on my IIS-7 the same code renders as:

```
<script src="/Scripts/vtickerjs"></script>
```

giving 404 not found.

I DONT have a "Scripts\vtickerjs" folder on my disk

Comment: Do you have following in your web.config: <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

    </modules>

 </system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vtickerjs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/vticker/jquery.vticker*"

  @section scripts {  
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vtickerjs")
}
```

If youn use `BundleConfig` then use `bundles` instead of  `Scripts`